# PartialView and unobtrusive client validation not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm currently using ASP.NET MVC3 RC and I'm using the unobtrusive JQuery validations as described by Brad Wilson on [his blog](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html). It works great but when I send my form (in Ajax) to the server, I do some server side validations and return the same row (that is included in a partial view) if my model state isn't valid. 2 problems with that :

1st : When I do a `return PartialView` in my action, all the unobtrusive attributes aren't rendered. I found a "non elegant" way to do it but when I do it, client validations are broken. After I return from my action, even if I call `jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse()` on my updated row, `$("form").valid()` always return true even if it's not the case.

2nd : I want my rendered view to be render as a string on the server so I can send it back in a JsonResult (ex:`myJSonResult.html=RenderPartialToString("partialName",model)`).

Has a reference, there's my view (editInvitation) :

```
<td>
    <%= Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.ID,new{id="ID"}) %>
    <%= Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.GroupID,new{id="GroupID"})  %>
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { id = "Name" })%><%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Name) %>
</td>
<td>
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { id = "Email" })%>  <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Email) %>
</td>
<td>
    <%: Model.Status.ToFriendlyName()%>
</td>
<td>
  <%= InvitationsViewModel.RenderActions(Model, Html, InvitationsViewModel.CreateRowID(Model.ID))%>
</td>
```

And my controller action :

```
if (TryUpdateModel(invitation))
{
    validModel = true;
    //Other stuff
}
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
     //TODO : I return a partial view but I would prefer to return a JSonResult with the rendered view as a string in an Property of my JSon result
     return PartialView(validModel ? "DisplayInvitation" : "EditInvitation", invitation);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally make it worked. This is how :

```
HtmlHelper helper = GetHelper();
MvcHtmlString partialView = helper.Partial("myView" , model);
var result = new { success = ModelState.IsValid, html = partialView.ToString() };
return Json(result);
```

There's the helper functions:

```
protected HtmlHelper GetHelper()
{
    return GetHelper(string.Empty);
}
protected HtmlHelper GetHelper(string formID)
{
    HtmlHelper helper = new HtmlHelper(getViewContext(formID), new ViewPage { ViewData = this.ViewData });
    helper.EnableClientValidation(isClientValidationEnabled());
    helper.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript(isUnobtrusiveJavascriptEnabled());
    return helper;
}
private ViewContext getViewContext(string formID)
{
    var vc = new ViewContext(this.ControllerContext, new WebFormView(this.ControllerContext, "~/Views/Home/Index.aspx"), this.ViewData, new TempDataDictionary(), new System.IO.StringWriter());
    vc.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = isUnobtrusiveJavascriptEnabled();
    vc.ClientValidationEnabled = isClientValidationEnabled();
    vc.FormContext = new FormContext { FormId = formID };
    return vc;
}
```

I'm not sure it's the best way to do it but it worked for me. Let's hope the ASP.NET MVC team would provide an easier way to render a view as a string.

Thanks