# ASP.NET MVC 3: Required steps for unobtrusive client-side validation of dynamic/AJAX content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

What are the complete set of **Steps Required** for client-side unobtrusive validation to work for dynamically inserted form fields?

### Relevant SO posts

[ASP.NET MVC 3 unobtrusive client-side validation with dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124992/asp-net-mvc-3-unobtrusive-client-side-validation-with-dynamic-content) - He needed the unobtrusive validation attributes to show up in the generated HTML and did so by calling `BeginForm`

[ASP.Net MVC 3 validation on AjaxForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938684/asp-net-mvc-3-validation-on-ajaxform) - The asker was using `Ajax.BeginForm` which uses MicrosoftAjax instead of JQuery.validation.

[PartialView and unobtrusive client validation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187742/partialview-and-unobtrusive-client-validation-not-working) - He had the problem with unobtrusive validation attributes not showing up and overrode `ViewContext.FormContext` as a workaround.

[ASP.NET MVC 3: Generate unobtrusive validation when BeginForm is on the layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997269/asp-net-mvc-3-generate-unobtrusive-validation-when-beginform-is-on-the-layout) - Workaround for unobtrusive validation attributes not showing up in HTML

### Relevant Links

Brad Wilson's [Unobtrusive Client Validation in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html)

[The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part  1](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-1)

[The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

[Unobtrusive Client-side Validation with Dynamic Contents in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/03/05/unobtrusive-client-side-validation-with-dynamic-contents-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

At this point I believe the following is a complete set of requirements:

1. Create a form with `Html.BeginForm`
2. Turn on `ClientValidationEnabled`
3. Turn on `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled`
4. Set appropriate validation attributes on the model's properties (*not* fields)
5. If the Html Helpers being used to create the form elements are not on the same form as the `Html.BeginForm` call, use a relevant workaround (see [workaround 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187742/partialview-and-unobtrusive-client-validation-not-working) and [workaround 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997269/asp-net-mvc-3-generate-unobtrusive-validation-when-beginform-is-on-the-layout))
6. Include `jquery`, `jquery.validate.js`, and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` files, in that order
7. Verify that the unobtrusive validation attributes are present in the HTML
8. If using custom validators:

   - ensure that they are added to `jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters`
   - ensure that they are added to the jQuery validation plugin by calling `jQuery.validator.addMethod`.
   - ensure that the above happen before `$(document).ready()` as at that point it's too late
9. Call `jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse` or `jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parseElement` on elements added dynamically after the initial page load.

Comment: No need for step 2 and step 6 also need jquery.js.

Comment: Why isn't step two needed, according to Brad Wilson's blog post linked above it's required?

Comment: `ensure that the above happen before $(document).ready() as at that point it's too late` That's what fixed it for me.