# Jquery MVC 4 Client side Validation Won't Work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use the jQuery validation plugin on a simple MVC 4 application - something I've done in MVC 3 with no problems, but I can't get it working at all.

I want the validation to fire when:

1 - my control looses focus .

2- on form submit.

Any ideas on what I've missed would be appreciated !

**Script references in _Layout.cshtml**

```
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - AWC Web Console</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
```

**Index.cshtml markup with validation JS applied in Doc ready function**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

        alert("doc ready");

        // JQuery client validation
        $("#prodIdFilterForm").validate(
            {
                onsubmit: true,
                rules: {
                    productId_str: {required: true, minlength: 10, number:true }
                },
                messages: { productId_str: "product Id must be entered" },
                // Force validation when control looses focus 
                onfocusout: function (element) {
                    alert("onfocusout");   // not entering this block !
                    $("#productId_str").removeAttr('style');
                    $("#productId_str").valid();   // fire validation
                    $(element).valid();
                }
                ,
                showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList)
                {
                    if (errorList.length > 0)
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < errorList.length; i++)
                        {
                            $("#" + errorList[i].element.id).css({ 'background-color': '#FFDFDF' });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
            );

    });  // DocReady

</script>
```

**Body of form markup**

```html
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Messages";
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@using ( Html.BeginForm("SelectProduct", "WMSMessages", Model, FormMethod.Post, new {  @id = "prodIdFilterForm"} ) )
{
   <fieldset class="filtering">
      <legend>SelectExtensions Product</legend>
      <div>
         <b>Product Id:</b>
         @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.productId_str, new { @id ="productId_str"}  )

         <div class="filterSubmitBox">
            <input type="submit" value="Show Messages" />
         </div>   
      </div>
   </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: BTW - I know the docready <script> block is missing it's </script> tag - I'm not used to formatting code in my posts (newbie !)

Comment: I can't believe it - I removed the 3rd script referenced in _Layout.cshtml : <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> and the validation started working - Can anyone enlichten me as to why ?

Comment: see my answer for detailed explanation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For client side  validataion microsoft uses jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js file. 
[Client side validation asp.net mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/javascript/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript)

> Enabling Client-Side Validation
>
> To enable client-side validation in ASP.NET MVC 3, you must set two
>   flags and you must include three JavaScript files.
>
> Open the application's Web.config file. Verify that
>   ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled are set to
>   true in the application settings. The following fragment from the root
>   Web.config file shows the correct settings:

```
 <appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
 </appSettings>
```

Setting UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled to true enables unobtrusive Ajax and unobtrusive client validation. When you use unobtrusive validation, the validation rules are turned into HTML5 attributes. HTML5 attribute names can consist of only lowercase letters, numbers, and dashes

for example if you said required attribue for email and with its error message. it will append data-attributes to element like this.

```
 <input data-val="true"
        data-val-required="Email is required (we promise not to spam you!)."
        id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="" />
```

Setting ClientValidationEnabled to true enables client-side validation. By setting these keys in the application Web.config file, you enable client validation and unobtrusive JavaScript for the entire application. You can also enable or disable these settings in individual views or in controller methods using the following code:

for more info :

1. [Asp.net MVC validation](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-1)
2. [MVC client side validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538082/asp-net-mvc-3-required-steps-for-unobtrusive-client-side-validation-of-dynamic)

Comment: Thanks for this! As noted, I had to make sure that the js file " jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" was loaded and that I added those two entries into the web.config.