# MVC5 - JQuery Unobtrusive client-side validation not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm working on a MVC webapplication (upgraded from MVC4 to MVC5) and I can't get the clientside validation working. So in order to rule things out i've created a default empty MVC application.

Unfortunately I still can't get things working, the contactform keeps submitting to the server and afterworths showing an error message from the server because the viewmodel is invalid.

This is my code;

**Contact.cshtml**

```
@model BLL.DTO.ContactDTO
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact","Home", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "contactform"}))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Firstname)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Firstname)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Firstname)

    <input type="submit" value="Verzenden"/>
}

<address>
    One Microsoft Way<br />
    Redmond, WA 98052-6399<br />
    <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr>
    425.555.0100
</address>

<address>
    <strong>Support:</strong> <a href="mailto:Support@example.com">Support@example.com</a><br/>
    <strong>Marketing:</strong> <a href="mailto:Marketing@example.com">Marketing@example.com</a>
</address>

@*@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#contactform").validate({
            debug: false
        });
    </script>    
}*@
```

**ContactDTO.cs**

```
public class ContactDTO : BaseDTO
{
    [Required (ErrorMessage = ErrorConstants.ThisFieldIsRequired)]
    [Display(Name = "Voornaam")]
    [MaxLength(75)]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = ErrorConstants.ThisFieldIsRequired)]
    [Display(Name = "Achternaam")]
    [MaxLength(75)]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Website")]
    public string Website { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = ErrorConstants.ThisFieldIsRequired)]
    [Display(Name = "Opmerkingen")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/msval").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"));
```

**web.config**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")*@
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/msval")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

As you probably can see in the code fragments I've also tried jquery.validate.js, but this doesn't work either.. I prefer to use the default unobtrusive validation, but unfortunately it keeps submitting the form to the server. I've also read several other topics ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737907/client-side-validation-not-working-in-asp-net-mvc5-with-bootstrap), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154309/jquery-mvc-4-client-side-validation-wont-work)) and while the issues look similar, it doesn't solve my problem. What could this be..?

Comment: You need both validate and validate-unobtrusive. Which will happen if you only include `~/bundles/jqueryval` because its mask matches `query.validate.unobtrusive` too. If you include both bundles, then with their current masks you will include `unobtrusive` twice.

Comment: Where is your controller ?

Comment: You also need to show us your controller for us to know if you handled if the model passed to the view is valid or not.

Comment: Un-comment `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` so its included and comment out `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/msval")`

Comment: @GSerg, thnx that was it.. Now seems to be working in my test application.. Will make the same changes to the normal application

Comment: @Heyyou, that was because I wasn't aware that both files where needed and I only wanted to use the unobtrusive validation

Comment: @GSerg, solved that was it indeed:)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the validation was not working due to my class library namespace and default models namespace was not matching hence the validation not working.
I have corrected it and now its working fine.