# Client-side validation not working in ASP.NET MVC5 with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

Running Visual Studio 2013, I created a new ASP.NET MVC (5) project, with Bootstrap.

However, I'm unable to get unobtrusive client-side validation working.

The model has `[Required]` attributes on the relevant properties and the view has `ValidationMessageFor...` tags for each field in the form.

However, submitting the form causes the form to postback to server before validation messages appear.

Using NuGet, I've installed `jquery.validate` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` and added them to the jquery bundle in `App_Start`.

Yet it continues to stubbornly post back to server. F12 dev tools shows no JS errors/warnings.

Has anybody else come across this issue (can't see anything in SO relating to MVC 5 specifically) and do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you check the html that its generating if it has the `data-val` and other validation attributes?

Comment: @WannaCSharp Thanks. Yes, the data-val attributes are all there as expected

Comment: Does it work when you remove the Bootstrap JavaScript?

Comment: @jHilscher Thanks. No, unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: I've just created a new MVC app from the start and validation works without any issue. I cannot for the life of me find a rational reason why the first app doesn't work. I've starting copying the code and views over one by one, so if it stops working I can pinpoint the reason. Other than that, totally out of ideas.

Comment: Further to my last message, I've now migrated all the code and views over to the 'new' application and it all works. Frustrating - never got to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem.  Comparing the generated HTML with a site that worked, I noticed that at the end of the document, there was this:

```
<script src="/bundles/jqueryval"></script>
```

...whereas the bundle should have been expanded like this:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

I looked in App_Start/BundleConfig.cs, and sure enough, the JQuery validation bundle had not been defined in `RegisterBundles`. I had to add:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

Why this was missing, I don't know. I started with a new, clean project.

It's pretty shoddy that there's no compile-time error when you reference an undefined bundle. Even an always-on run-time error would be better than silent failure. So much time wasted!

EDIT: turns out I didn't have the JQuery validation scripts in my project, either. I had to add them via NuGet ("Microsoft JQuery Unobtrusive Validation").

Comment: This answer helped me the most - I had the bundle defined in the App_Start/BundleConfig.cs file, BUT there wasn't a reference to using it in my _Layout.cs file. So, simply adding the  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquerybal")  line made it all magically work.

Comment: This answer did the job for me too. Adding the @Scripts.Render was required in addition to the step above

Answer (score 22):

I was having same problem. The solution is to add .js reference to master page (_Layout.cshtml)

1. jquery.validate.js
2. jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

Comment: Sorry for delay in responding. It was already there - this is what was driving me mad. In the end the solution for me was to copy everything into a new project.

Comment: The trick (for me) was to make sure I wasn't loading it twice... I had it on the "_Layout.cshtml" and also as part of "Scripts" at the bottom of my "view.cshtml" pages... I commented out the "Scripts" and viola... it suddenly worked as advertised.

Answer (score 16):

Have you verified `<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />` in web.config?

Otherwise, this provides a good overview: [ASP.NET MVC 3: Required steps for unobtrusive client-side validation of dynamic/AJAX content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538082/asp-net-mvc-3-required-steps-for-unobtrusive-client-side-validation-of-dynamic?rq=1). Also valid for MVC5.

Comment: This combined with `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />` solved it for me. (MVC5)

Comment: But the weird thing was I simply created a brand new APP and copied my code back in and it all started working.

Comment: Out of the box, the MVC 5 template includes these by default.

Answer (score 9):

At the bottom of the page add:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

and everything will work fine.

Comment: This was missing from `_Layout.cshtml` for me.

Comment: Doh. Quite why this still isn't in there by default in the starter template I don't know!

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue when I was playing with my first MVC project. The issue was at the end that I didn't **include the input elements to the form element**. Yes, very stupid. Make sure you create the form, for instance :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FieldA)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FieldA)

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FieldB)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FieldB)

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since tour using MVC instead of adding to every edit view, you could add in the view/shared folder at `_Layout.cshtml`.

just add

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

at the bottom of _Layout.cshtml, on top of

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

in this case the script will effect every page that uses that layout.

Comment: In my project the render line was missing from _layout.cshtml. Make sure it is inserted between jquery and bootstrap :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a little late to the game but this does add more to validation and I found it to be very helpful. Sometimes conflicting javascript/jQuery Plugin/API references (eg:searchMeme.js) that reference other jquery versions can cause problems so I create unique bundles for account login actions. These are the steps I would take:

**1.** Create a separate layout **~/Views/Shared/_AccountLayout.cshtml** for **AccountController.cs**.

**2.** Create new **~/Account/_ViewStart.csthml** with:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AccountLayout.cshtml";
}
```

**3.** Create two bundles for css & js in **BundleConfig.cs** for AccountController:

```
   bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/accountcss").Include(
                "~/Content/site.css",
                "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                "~/Content/font-awesome.css")); /*if using font-awesome */

   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/accountjs").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));//must be after jquery validate
```

**4.** Reference the bundles in both ends of **head** & **body** in **_AccountLayout.cshtml** as such:

```
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
         @Styles.Render("~/Content/accountcss")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        @this.RenderSection("MetaContent", false)
        @this.RenderSection("Styles", false)
        </head>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/accountjs")
        @this.RenderSection("Scripts", false)
        </body>
```

*NOTE: *Make sure bootstrap is after jqueryval in bundle*

**5.** Make sure you have `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` for each input field within **~/Account/Login.cshtml**, **~/Account/Register.cshtml**, etc... respectively.

```
<div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
          <div class="col-md-10">
               @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
          </div>
</div>
```

**6.** Use DataAnnotations to create additional custom validation errors `[RegularExpression(@"^([\w]{2,20})@?([\w]{2,20}).?[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$", ErrorMessage="")]`:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*Username is required."), RegularExpression(@"^[\w+]{3,10}\s?([\w+]{3,15})$", ErrorMessage = "*Username can only be Alphanumeric"),StringLength(25, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long and no bigger than {1} characters.", MinimumLength = 5)]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

**7. (optional)** Lastly, if you changed the DataAnotation for Password then you **MUST** also change the Password Policy in **~/App_Start/IdentityConfig.cs** as such:

```
manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
{
    RequiredLength = 6,
    RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
    RequireDigit = true,
    RequireLowercase = true,
    RequireUppercase = true,
};
```

**8. (optional)** Also, check out this [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/how-to-customize-password-policy-in-Asp-Net-identity/) on Roles etc..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, my solution is clear all history in browser (cache, cookies, form, ...) and everything work correctly.

Comment: Interesting, a bad cache could have been an issue I guess. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys this is a certain solution
**1)** First Add Following Items your Webconfig file

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
```

**2)**
Ex(Index.cshtml) add this jquery source to up side your cshtml

```
<body>
 <script src="~/Content/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.11/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

for more https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLe7WbsuHPU

Answer (score 0):

I think that `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` is missing from the template. I do get the errors, but not the messages.

Comment: Sorry for delay in responding. That wasn't the issue for me, unfortunately. I did I file-by-file copy and paste in to a new project and everything started working. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing this answer for future readers.I was dealing with the same issue and found the problem is with the sequence of the render scripts. 
Make Sure

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

is before

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

in _layout.cshtml .
The layout bottom part should look like follow.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```