# jquery validation attribute not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation, client-side-validation

I have two models

```
public class UserDetail
    {
        [Required]
        public string username { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string name { get; set; }
        public LogInDetail LogInDetail { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
public class LogInDetail
    {
        [Required]
        public string username { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string password { get; set; }

        public UserDetail UserDetail { get; set; }
    }
```

and a view having model `UserDetail`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.LogInDetail.username)
            @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.LogInDetail.username)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.LogInDetail.username)

            @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.LogInDetail.password)
            @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.LogInDetail.password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.LogInDetail.password)
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        }
```

if i try to submit the form without any entry it should show client side validation (as i have added `[Required]` attribute to the properties of `LogInDetails`). I have also added jquery library for validation. But i am not getting any client side validation error message. Please help me

Comment: Which jquery libraries did you include? Sounds like the javascript isn't there.

Comment: <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you include jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js too. For a complete list of requirements for automatic validation see this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8539211/848739