# Can i return a Partial view and a Json object from my action method at the same time

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

i have the following action method, that returns a partial view `_create`. but is there a way to pass a Json object such as `return Json(new { IsSuccess = "True" },` with the Partial view.

My Action method looks as follow:-

```
try
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     var v = repository.GetVisit(visitid);
     if (!(v.EligableToStart(User.Identity.Name)))
     { 
       return View("NotFound"); 
     }
     vlr.VisitID = visitid;
     repository.AddVisitLabResult(vlr);
     repository.Save();
     ViewBag.LabTestID = new SelectList(repository.FindAllLabTest(), "LabTestID", "Description", vlr.LabTestID);
     // return Json(new { IsSuccess = "True" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     @ViewBag.status = "Added Succsfully";
     return  PartialView("_create",vlr) ;
   }
}
```

**::-UPDATED-::**

what i am trying to do as follow:-

1. i am calling the action method using ajax.beginform

   ```
   using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateAll", "VisitLabResult", new AjaxOptions
   {
     HttpMethod = "Post",
     UpdateTargetId = item.ToString(),
     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
     OnSuccess = string.Format("disableform({0})", Json.Encode(item)),
   }))
   ```
2. after successfully receiving the response from the server ,, the Onsuccess script will be executed,,, the script simply disable the form:-

   ```
   function disableform(id) {
       $('#' + id + ' :input').prop("disabled", true);
   }
   ```

The problem is that **the script will always disable the form even is some validation error occurs**,, so what i was trying to achieve is to return a JSON with the partial view that indicate if the ModelState.IsValid was valid or not,, **and if it was not valid to keep the form enabled to allow the user to correct the validation errors.**

BR

Answer (score 0):

You can return ONLY ONE view from action method, if at all you want to pass other information,make use of ViewData or ViewBag

```
ViewBag.IsSuccess =  "True";
```

Or

```
ViewData["IsSuccess"] = "True";
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can return only the view and pass JSON as the model, or ViewBag (I recommend model.)

Comment: I think that neither the viewbag nor the viewmodel will solve my problem, PLEASE CHECK MY UPDATE TO SEE MORE DETAILS OF THE PROBLEM I AM FACING

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply extend the model that you are already passing to the View adding the property `IsSuccess`?

ViewBag or ViewData are evil in my opinion. Try to always use a ViewModel when returning data to the view.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases I used following solution:

In your ajax form definition set:

```
OnComplete = "yourCallback"
```

Then:

```
yourCallback = function(response){
  var json = response.responseJSON;
  if(json.success){
     alert('Well done!');
  } else {
     var form = $('#formId');
     form.html(json.html);
     form.removeData("validator").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
     $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
  }
}
```

Your controller should return something like this:

```
var result = new { success = false, html = helper.Partial("_YourPartial", model) };
return Json(result);
```

Where `helper` helps you to add validation to your partial view. (Described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4270511/952023)